# How to create a log in system with meteor?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I am trying to get the grasp of meteor, but I am a certain beginner. Going to ask for help with a very basic thing here.

How do I create 2 forms (for login and password input) and a button that will register an account using `Accounts.createUser(options, [callback])`

I need to understand the very basic thing of how to tie two forms to the function.

EDIT: I tried a thing. Acting totally blind though.

```
    if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.login.account = function () {
    if (Meteor.user() == null) {
        return 
            <form id="login">
                <input type="email" id="email" />
                <input type="text" id="logintext" />
                <input type="password" id="password" />
            </form>

        };
    };
  Template.login.events({
    'click input' : Sumbit();
    })
  }

function Sumbit(){
    var login, password, email;
    document.getElementById('email').value = email; 
    document.getElementById('logintext').value = login; 
    document.getElementById('password').value = password; 
    Accounts.createUser(login, email, password)
}
```

Comment: @BigTeddy is right. Plus you can't write your templates directly in javascript files, you have to create a separate file with a `.html` extension.

Comment: @mquandalle I did make a .html with templates there. Just didn't add it here, my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meteor already provides you with a quite decent user-system: [accounts-api](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_api)

And for the login-form: Simply add the accounts-ui package (`meteor add accounts-ui`) and add the function to your template:

```
<template name="main">
    {{loginButtons}} <!--These are your login-buttons -->
</template>
```

For further information: [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#accountsui) are the docs for the accounts-ui package.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I would still like to know if there is a 'manual' way to do this, for learning purporses. Because not knowing how to put an input into a variable is stupid

Answer (score 1):

There is a manual way too do it. Check out this article by Ben: http://blog.benmcmahen.com/post/41741539120/building-a-customized-accounts-ui-for-meteor

The trick is creating a form, taking the values from that form on submission and passing them to Accounts.createUser().

Passing those values, let's say email and password, allow Meteor to do the heavy lifting in creating the account.

Accounts.createUser() in the docs:
http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_createuser

With unique fields like age, or first name, for your sign up page, put those as nested details within profile.

It's a very similar process for logging the user in. Except instead of 'Account.createUser' you're going to use 'Meteor.loginWithPassword'. You pass the details the user types in from login form you create to that and Meteor will check out if the user exists and then create a sessions for them.

This is all my beginner dev/Meteor understanding. But I'm confident that's the basic flow.